# An App in AppExchange is aloha or not

Tags: appexchange

How to identify an app in salesforce appExchange has Aloha feature Enabled or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The naming convention of "Aloha" has now gone away. Instead, all Managed Packages will no longer count against system limits.

[This blog post](http://blogs.salesforce.com/company/2012/08/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-new-salesforce-appexchange.html) explains why Salesforce said Aloha to Aloha apps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @sfdc_nerd.. May i know from which release, the above link is introduced?

Comment: Based on the timing of the blog post, I would guess around Summer 12, but I don't think the timing was tied directly to a product release.